# Get BizTalk SSO Config Value from PowerShell

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Case:

I am an administrator of some BizTalk servers. On one of them we have an service running, which is pulling metadata and documents from an external webservice.

From time to time we have to check, that our BizTalk is current with the metadata values from the remote webservice. We have a website for our checks, where we can see the actual numbers from the documents locally and the the documents ready for download.

Solution:

I've written a script in PowerShell, which is pulling the metadata from the remote webservice and comparing it with our local database, to check if our data is current.

Problem:

The webservice login, the database connection-string and some other values are saved in the SSO-configuration of the local BizTalk-Server. I've searched, but did not find a solution to access the production data on the SSO, instead of using my own values in separate XML-file, where the script reads is values from.

Comment: Can you post the script?